# arcpy calculate row[0] from dict value

Tags: arcpy

I am trying to use an update cursor on a shapefile to calculate a row from a dictionary and must be missing something very simple. below is my code

so my dictionary is called adict

```
adict = {'source': {0: u'SUN', 1: u'DAN'}, u'WORK_TYPE': {0: u'FRA', 1: u'UKB'}, u'API_NUM': {0: '422973', 1: '422873'}
```

And i am trying to calculate worktype in my shapefile.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(myshapefile, ['API_NUM','WORK_TYPE']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in adict['API_NUM'].values():
            row[1]=adict[row[0]]
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            print 'no'
```

i'm trying to set the row value on the shapefile to the corresponding dictionary value.

---

I am trying to calculate my work_type column in the shapefile with the work_type value from the dictionary based on the matching `API_NUM`, so for `api = 422873`, the worktype would be `UKB`.

If i were using geopandas, i would convert the dict to a dataframe and merge on api. Using arcpy right now i am iterating through both sets of data and calculating the work value from the corresponding dict data, but because there are so many records in both sets, it's taking a while using that method. so i thought a dictionary may be faster. I know i could convert to array, then to a table, but that just seems like a bunch of steps.

Comment: seems to be more like a Python problem, that belongs to StackOverflow site

Comment: I had it tagged arcpy and python and one of the admins removed the python tag for a reason i don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per your additional comments, I think you need to reconstruct your dictionary, and then pull the values from your new dict using the field value from `API_NUM`.  See my `# Comments` in the code below which hopefully give a bit of detail what the changed lines are doing.

```
adict = {'422973': {'source': 'SUN', 'WORK_TYPE': 'FRA'}, '422873': {'source': 'DAN', 'WORK_TYPE': 'UKB'}}

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(myshapefile, ['API_NUM','WORK_TYPE']) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        if row[0] in adict: # Does the API_NUM exist as a key in the dictionary?
            row[1] = adict[row[0]]['WORK_TYPE'] # Find the WORK_TYPE for the current row's API_NUM
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            print 'API_NUM {} not in dictionary'.format(row[0])
```

I also find that when working with large dictionaries (especially dictionaries of dictionaries) that it is often clearer to put different entries on new lines:

```
adict = {
         '422973': {'source': 'SUN', 'WORK_TYPE': 'FRA'}, 
         '422873': {'source': 'DAN', 'WORK_TYPE': 'UKB'}
        }
```

Comment: Brilliant and thank you, works perfectly. i restructured my dictionary like you recommended and yes, it makes much more sense.

Answer (score 0):

I actually think i solved it,

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(myshapefile, ['API_NUM','WORK_TYPE']) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    if row[0] in adict['API_NUM'].values():
        row[1]=adict['WORK_TYPE'][0]  ## <- here is what i was missing
        cursor.updateRow(row)
    else:
        print 'no'
```

Comment: Do you want the `row[1]` value to _always_ be set to `'FRA'` ?  As that is what you are pulling from your dictionary, every time.

Comment: you sir, are correct, which is wrong, on my part. How would i write it correctly?

Comment: Are you wanting to use the value from `row[0]` to select the WORK_TYPE from the dictionary?

Comment: yes, i am trying to calculate my work_type column in the shapefile with the work_type value from the dictionary based on the matching API_NUM

Comment: So if your `API_NUM` is `422873` (from your dictionary above) what would you expect your `WORK_TYPE` to be, and why?

Comment: so for api = 422873, the worktype would be UKB. If i were using geopandas, i would convert the dict to a dataframe and merge on *api*. Using arcpy right now i am iterating through both sets of data and calculating the work value from the corresponding dict data, but because there are so many records in both sets, it's taking a while using that method. so i thought a dictionary may be faster. I know i could convert to array, then to a table, but that just seems like a bunch of steps.

Comment: I have added your additional information from these comments into your question and posted an answer based on this extra info.